# Validation Two Check Boxs

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps-canvas

I have Two Checkbox taking Choices from Sharepoint List. lets say First check box having 1,2,3 and Second Check Box having jan, Feb and March. If we selected first Checkbox 1value then want to show Feb in second check box automatically.like that if we selected 2 value in first check box then want Mar value in Second check box

Could anyone please help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per your description, you want to create cascading checkboxes using SharePoint and PowerApps.

Two blogs about cascading checkboxes for your reference:
[Cascading Checkbox with Gallery in Power Apps](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Community-Blog/Cascading-Checkbox-with-Gallery-in-Power-Apps/ba-p/679855)
[Multi Select Checkbox List In PowerApps SharePoint Forms](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/multi-select-checkbox-list-in-powerapps-sharepoint-forms/)